# How long was an observable delayed for when using debounceTime?

Tags: rxjs

In this example: https://rxviz.com/v/0oqKpbWJ the delay in time from the first interval to when a value is emitted from the debounceTime operator is 4 seconds.

Is there a way to know that/be able to log the window that a debounce has debounced for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need timeInterval operator https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/timeInterval

Put it after the debounceTime

Update:

okay, I got it. You need a custom operator for sure. Try this

```
import { fromEvent, OperatorFunction } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, tap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const result = clicks.pipe(debounceTimeWithIntervalTracking(1000));
result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

function debounceTimeWithIntervalTracking<T>(time: number): OperatorFunction<T, { value: T, delayedFor: number }> {
  let startedTime = new Date().getTime();
  let restart = true;
  return src$ => src$.pipe(
    tap(() => {
      if (restart) {
        startedTime = new Date().getTime();
      }
      restart = false;
    }),
    debounceTime(time),
    map(value => {
      const delayedFor = new Date().getTime() - startedTime;
      restart = true;
      return { value, delayedFor };
    })
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that's quite what I'm looking for. That will give me the time between emissions, but not the time window that debounce debounced for.

Comment: however... if I coupled it w/ switch map... i may be able to put together an operator that does measure that...

Comment: no, that won't work... i'd need something like a "group by debounce" and compare initial and final timestamps